# Do we know that energy of a system is conserved if no external forces do work on it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, momentum, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

[image]

This question is from K&K's intro book on mechanics. The larger block with the quarter circle missing has mass $M$ and the smaller block has mass $m$. The goal is to find the speed $v$ of the smaller block as it leaves the larger block. There is no friction anywhere. The tricky part here is that there is a recoil of the larger block due to the normal force from the smaller block. I am lost as to how to get to the solution.

Resources online give this equation: $$mgR=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}MV^2$$ where $V$ is the speed of the larger block after the smaller block loses contact. I do not see where this equation comes from. It seems to suggest that the mechanical energy of *the system* is conserved.

I understand that in the frame of the small block, we have that $mgR=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ But if $$mgR=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}MV^2$$ is also true then $$\frac{1}{2}MV^2=0$$ That is, that the larger block garnered no speed due to the smaller block; which certainly is not the case.

My *guess* as to why $mgR=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is invalid is, since the larger block recoiled, the smaller blocks displacement vector was not truly perpendicular to the normal force. Thus the normal force (nonconservative?) did some work on the small block.

My main question is in the title but it is mostly this: How do we know $$mgR=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}MV^2$$ is true in this case?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: The equation for the small mass is wrong, because you are ignoring the work made by the normal force. you need to consider the conservation of mechanical energy for the entire system, and if so you can ignore the normal force as an internal force.

Comment: @PatoGalmarini normal forces between the big and small block are internal forces to the system, but this does not imply we can ignore them; they can and do work in this case, most visibly on the larger block. The reason we do not need to consider these internal forces when finding the final velocities is that we can find the solution just from the conservation laws, without careful consideration of the internal forces.

Comment: @PatoGalmarini But you're right that in the frame of the small block, the equation $mgR=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is wrong. This is because in that frame $v=0$.

Comment: @JánLalinský yes, that is what I meant, conservation of mechanical energy takes that into account implicitly. I guess I was not that clear. Also, by "frame of the small block" I assumed "I analyze teh block in isolation", otherwise, as you stated, v=0

Comment: Voting to reopen. Obviously a conceptual question rather than a "do my homework for me" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The work energy theorem is essentially a statement that energy is conserved whenever there are no non-conservative external forces acting on a system. This is so because in order for work to be done on an object, there must be a force on the object as the definition of work is:
$$W=\int_1^2\vec F\cdot d\vec s.$$If one of the forces in question is *non-conservative* then it will do work and the system will loose energy by an amount in accordance with the above definition.
So if we take as the system in the problem, the combined small and large blocks, then there are no *external* *dissipative* forces acting on the system. All of the forces we can draw on a diagram are internal to the system except for the external force of gravity. Thus, we are able to conclude that energy is conserved for the system. Since the initial configuration of the system is such that all of the system's energy is tied up in the gravitational potential energy of the smaller block and the final configuration is such that the small block has fallen by a height of $R$ and both blocks are set in motion, then if the total energy is constant, the gravitational energy of the smaller block has been converted into the kinetic energy of the small and large block system:
$$mgR={1\over 2}mv^2+{1\over 2}MV^2.$$

Comment: No external *net* forces yes? Gravity is certainly *acting* on the system although not doing any work. Thank you for clarification either way.

Comment: @ChrisChristopherson gravity is certainly doing work, where do you think mgR comes from

Comment: Yes you are right, I meant that the only nonconservative forces acting on the system are internal and thus the total mechanical energy of *the system* is conserved.

Comment: @ChrisChristopherson Glad it helped! Yes, I should have mentioned gravity as an external force rather than having left it implicit. I will edit the post accordingly so that it doesn't perhaps confuse someone less in tune with what's going on.

Comment: @ChrisChristopherson there are no non-conservative forces. If there was friction, that *would be* a non-conservative force, and it would spoil the conservation of mechanical energy. It does not matter whether the friction is internal or external, it affects mechanical energy conservation.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus that is not what the work-energy theorem (in its original form) says. It concerns kinetic energy only, and involves all forces, external and internal. Work of all forces, external and internal, equals change of kinetic energy of all particles making up the system.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus the statement about energy conservation is not valid in mechanics in general. Consider a subsystem of particles in Newtonian gravitational system of many particles. Only conservative forces act there, but energy of the subsystem (howsoever we define it, e.g. as kinetic plus potential energy of any subsystem) is not conserved, because it exchanges energy with the rest of the system.

Comment: @JánLalinský That is an excellent point thanks for sharing. I had not really thought about that, however, I can see that even in the above problem, if one considers as a subsystem the small block, then even in the absence of dissipative forces, energy is not conserved for it separately as a subsystem because it exchanges energy with the large block.